# status.response is not updated after responding to the event

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Jack sent me a meeting invite. And I responded to that meeting, in this case `tentativelyAccepted` by

```
POST /me/events/${eventId}/tentativelyAccept
{
  sendResponse: true
}
```

Then when I use

```
GET /me/events
```

the **responseStatus.response** updated to `tentativelyAccepted` correctly.

However, **status.response** is still `none` which is wrong.

```
    {
        "responseStatus": {
            "response": "tentativelyAccepted",
            "time": "2018-02-05T03:15:49.3615414Z"
        },
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2018-02-05T18:30:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2018-02-05T19:30:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "location": {
            "displayName": "Office"
        },
        "recurrence": null,
        "attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "status": {
                    "response": "none",
                    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Jack",
                    "address": "jack@example.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "required",
                "status": {
                    "response": "none",
                    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Hongbo Miao",
                    "address": "Hongbo.Miao@example.com"
                }
            }
        ],
        "organizer": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Jack",
                "address": "jack@example.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

If I log in Jack's account, and run `GET /me/events`, **status.response** is `tentativelyAccepted` which is correct.

Comment: So historically only an _organizer_ could see the meeting response. I seem to recall seeing something about a change being rolled out that allowed attendees to see them but for the life of me I can't find it anywhere. Given this result however, I suspect I'm mistaken.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT yeah, in Microsoft Teams, if you change to other response, `status.response` will update correctly. But the Graph API does not update `status.response` correctly.

Comment: Interesting. It might be worth trying the `beta` endpoint. If the default behavior has changed in Outlook/Teams then it may be that this just hasn't landed in `v1.0` yet.